# Proper way to use Numeric type bounds for classes in scala

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism, implicit

**General question**: What is the proper way to define a generic class typed with a type which is `Numeric`, ideally without using any `implicit` in Scala 2?

**Specific example**: consider the following toy class which is built around Integer sequence:

```scala
class NewList(val values: Seq[Int]) {
    def +(x: Int): NewList = new NewList(values.map(_ + x))
}

val x = new NewList(List(1,2,3))
(x + 5).values  // ---> List(6, 7, 8)
```

Now suppose we want to make `NewList` generic, wrapping around any numeric sequence:

```scala
// Would not compile
class NewList[T: Numeric](val values: Seq[T]) {
    def +(x: T): NewList = new NewList(values.map(_ + x))
}
```

The code above would not compile due to some weird type mismatch

```
cmd2.sc:2: type mismatch;
 found   : T
 required: String
    def +(x: T): NewList[T] = new NewList(values.map(_ + x))
                                                         ^Compilation Failed

Compilation Failed
```

As far as I understand, this compilation error apparently means, that compiler could not resolve variable `x: T` to be of a `Numeric` type, and thus could not resolve type of arguments of `plus`. Trying to declare `+(x: Numeric[T])` or using `(implicit num: T => Numeric[T])` either in class definition or method definition would not help.

The only way to make the class compile and behave as expected is to use `plus` method of `implicitly[Numeric[T]]`:

```scala
class NewList[T: Numeric](val values: Seq[T]) {
    def +(x: T): NewList[T] = new NewList(values.map(implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(_, x)))
}

val x = new NewList(List(1,2,3))
(x + 5).values  // ---> List(6, 7, 8)
```

- Why couldn't compiler resolve method `plus` for `T`, even though it is declared as `Numeric` in the class definition?
- Is there any better way to solve this issue without use of ugly boilerplate `implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus`?
- Could we, in general, avoid `implicit`'s to handle such cases in scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why couldn't compiler resolve method plus for T, even though it is declared as Numeric in the class definition?

First, because `T` IS NOT a `Numeric`; rather it has an instance of `Numeric` **typeclass** associated with it
Second, even if `T` would be a `Numeric`, it would not have a `+` method; because, again, that is not how typeclasses work.
Check this: https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4

> Is there any better way to solve this issue without use of ugly boilerplate implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus?

Yes, just import the extension methods: `import Numeric.Implicits._` either at the top level or inside the `class` or the method.

> Could we, in general, avoid implicit's to handle such cases in scala?

`[T: Numeric]` is just sugar syntax for `(implicit ev: Numeric[T])` so no, you can't avoid `implicits`

Which is fine, really.